# Manually referencing a nuget installed DLL in the project

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-assembly

I am working on a solution that has multiple projects . In one of the project (say `Project A`) I have installed a nuget package say `Utility` and the function that I want to use is in `Utility.dll` . This add all dependencies of `Utility.dll` to project reference of `Project A` .

Now I have added just `Utility.dll` to another `Project B` in the same solution , by right click --> add reference --> existing items -->Browse --> Add.

This does not adds the dependencies of `Utility.dll` in project reference but after building all dependencies get copied to `/bin/debug` folder .

I am trying to find out:-

1. Can msbuild resolve the dependency of Utility.dll at runtime and automatically copy its dependencies ?
2. If , msbuild can resolve dependencies , does it refers some manifest file or it disassembles a dll and reads its dependency , as dependencies of `Utility.dll` are located in different folders in `/package` ?

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild only looks for related files (pdb,xml,..) but only for classic NuGet references.

I suggest only using NuGet to reference packages and never manually add direct references to a packages folder when using `packages.config`.

For projects using [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) in the csproj instead of the legacy packages.config method, these dependencies also flow transitively by default ([Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference))